# Chat client for android

Tags: java, android, chat, xmpp

I wanna build my own chat client using xmpp on android to chat with my own friends. Is it possible to build such kinda of apps on android which is specific to my own apps. people dont have to share there either gmail or facebook profiles to login to my chat client. I already have my own authentication process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You should try some XMPP API like [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/). Also you may need to provide server for which you can use [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp). For example see [here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/).

Answer (score 2):

For android creating XMPP client there are [ASMACK](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) library, You can also get sample application from [Jabbim client](http://dev.jabbim.cz/ajabbim)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its damn possible

Try Sinch, as its XMPP based and easy to integrate with your applications.

Sample Code: https://github.com/akberarslan/AndroidChatClient

Also explore Tokbox, Hope it will help.